# Unpacking dictionary into model

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

When unpacking with `**` i need to have the exactly same arguments as the constructor?

What i mean is, if i have an additional item in the dictionary, that should be ignored, i need to pop the item? Currently i am trying just unpack everything, and i am expecting that item would be immediately excluded, but i am getting this error:

```
  __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument
```

---

```
nagative = NegativeSentimentAnalysis(**negative_items)
```

---

```
class NegativeSentimentAnalysis(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sentiment = db.Column(db.String(500))
    topic = db.Column(db.String(500))

    def __init__(self, sentiment=None, topic=None):
        self.sentiment = user_id
        self.topic = topic
```

Comment: If you are not sure what your dict is going to be, then I would recommend not to do the automatic unpacking in the first place.

Comment: @user2990084 Except the question itself, I am just a little bit of curious about your method of doing `Negative Sentiment Analysis`. Can you give me some clue? Thanks

Comment: @yan9yu, you have multiples API to handle sentiment analysis. i am just saving the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply have `__init__` accept all keyword arguments:

```
    def __init__(self, sentiment=None, topic=None, **kw):
```

This will cause the leftover arguments be collected in `kw` which the method can ignore.  However, this comes with a caveat that you may have other code that construct this object that may need to fail.

Alternatively just filter out the arguments as noted in the other answer.

Comment: This works, but kind of hacky.  It should be the responsibility of the caller to supply the correct arguments.

Comment: @augurar good point, however this was more answering this part of OP's question: if i have an additional item in the dictionary, that should be ignored, i need to pop the item? No, but this way is hacky, will make note of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a new dict with the relevant keys and use that:

```
keys = {'sentiment', 'topic'}
kwargs = {k:v for k,v in negative_items.iteritems() if k in keys}
negative = NegativeSentimentAnalysis(**kwargs)
```